# check a string istitle and modify another string accordingly

Tags: python, regex

I have a slightly modified version of [this](https://github.com/vim-scripts/fortran_codecomplete.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/fortran_codecomplete.vim) vim plugin as:

```
class SyntaxElement:
    def __init__(self, pattern, closingline):
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.closingline = closingline
    def match(self, line): 
        """ Return (indent, closingline) or (None, None)"""
        match = self.pattern.search(line)
        if match:
            indentpattern = re.compile(r'^\s*')
            variablepattern = re.compile(r'\$\{(?P<varname>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\}')
            indent = indentpattern.search(line).group(0)
            closingline = self.closingline
            # expand variables in closingline
            while True:
                variable_match = variablepattern.search(closingline)
                if variable_match:
                    try:
                        replacement = match.group(variable_match.group('varname'))
                    except:
                        print("Group %s is not defined in pattern" % variable_match.group('varname'))
                        replacement = variable_match.group('varname')
                    try:
                        closingline = closingline.replace(variable_match.group(0), replacement)
                    except TypeError:
                        if replacement is None:
                            replacement = ""
                        closingline = closingline.replace(variable_match.group(0), str(replacement))
                else:
                    break
        else:
            return (None, None)
        closingline = closingline.rstrip()
        return (indent, closingline)


def fortran_complete():

    syntax_elements = [
        SyntaxElement(re.compile(r'^\s*\s*((?P<struc>(program)))\s*((?P<name>([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)))', re.IGNORECASE),
                      'End ${struc} ${name}' )..]
```

where I have only added `re.IGNORECASE`.

My problem is following:

Fortran is case insensitive. So, `PROGRAM`, `Program` and `program` is equivalent, which is the `${struc}` here. But, I also want to match the `End` case. So, if I write, `Program`, I want "End"; if I write, `PROGRAM`, I would like to have "END".

So, in other word, I want to check if `Program` is `istitle`, or `isupper` or `lower`, and change my "End" string accordingly.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please leave meaningful parts of code only

Comment: I am sorry, but I guess I need to show the `SyntaxElement` class, and at least one example of how it works. Or do you mean I need to show more?

Answer (score 0):

Regex to get the 'struc' group and compare.

```
if re.group('struc') == re.group('struc').title():
    end_stmt = 'End'
elif re.group('struc') == re.group('struc').lower():
    end_stmt = 'end'
elif re.group('struc') == re.group('struc').upper():
    end_stmt = 'END'
else:
    # etc.
    pass

syntax_elements = [
    SyntaxElement(..., end_stmt + '...')
```